# Azure APIM Data Level Authentication - How do people accomplish this?

Tags: azure-api-management

Scenario: Externally exposed API, connects to multiple backed Dbs.  Multiple customers can use the API, they obviously should only have access to their data. In the past this is done by separate accounts for each customer/user, and consequently each account would need setting up in each of the backend systems with the correct authorities.

Problem: I want to use Azure APIM.  I don't want the extra maintenance for each user in both the Azure APIM and the backend Dbs. I was wondering if anyone has any thoughts or cases where they accomplished this in a different way. Also the API may be built with access via one account with all access to tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are different ways to approach this but a common way I believe to do this would be using [Application Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles).

I don't believe this is really dependent on Azure APIM as such, but you can leverage [OAuth 2.0 support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad) to [pre-authorize  requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#configure-a-jwt-validation-policy-to-pre-authorize-requests) and in your backend, depending on the claims present in the token passed, you can allow/deny access to the data.

You backend would usually authenticate to the different DBs as itself with full access to all data and your backend would be tasked with making sure only people with the right claims can access the data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at Application Roles and the idea around claims.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use an API the user/customer has to register with the Developer Portal and get a **Subscription** to a given API and the **associated key**. So you have to authenticate them. When you publish APIs through Azure API Management, it's easy and common to secure access to those APIs by using subscription keys. Client applications that need to consume the published APIs must include a valid **subscription key** in HTTP requests when they make calls to those APIs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-subscriptions

The Developer Portal supports different authentication mechanisms including Azure AD. So if you plan to use Azure AD for your authentication for both portals you will need to configure it accordingly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad

Comment: Thank you. The problem we have is that the backend API requests are completed with a generic account i.e. we have multiple backend dbs and so not want to set up 1000's of users in each system, each with their separate access.